# SQL Sub Queries: States without Cats

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table called A10.  I want to create a view named A10T1 that will display the state abbreviation for every state that has no people with a cat value of Y.  I need to use subqueries but keep getting no output.

My current code is:

```
CREATE VIEW A10T1 AS
SELECT STATE
FROM A10
WHERE STATE IS NOT NULL AND ID IN
 (SELECT ID
  FROM A10
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING COUNT(ID) =
   (SELECT MIN(CATLOVERS)
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(ID) AS CATLOVERS
          FROM A10
          WHERE CAT = 'Y'
          GROUP BY STATE)))
ORDER BY STATE;
```

Comment: you have created the view. Run a select on the view to see the result

Comment: The result is a column called STATE with nothing in it... I should be seeing state abbreviations of at least a few states

Comment: Look at your HAVING clause. On the one hand, you take the MIN of counts of people with cats by state. (This should be zero if there are ANY states with zero cat lovers, but otherwise it will not be zero.) On the other hand, you look for states with a TOTAL count of ID's equal to this MIN number. If that MIN number is in fact zero, why should the TOTAL count of ID's be zero in the states you are looking for? This is way too complicated (and therefore not worth fixing), but it may help to understand the logic flaw in your attempt.

Comment: I want to select states where the count of IDs with a Cat value of Y is equal to zero... Are you able to explain what you mean in greater detail?  Feel like that could be why I'm getting no output... How would I adjust my having clause?

Answer (score 2):

Pity someone just gave you an assignment answer, you get to practice copy/paste that way but not much learning happens.

Why did your query fail?

Run this query by itself:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS CATLOVERS
      FROM A10
      WHERE CATLOVERS = 'Y'
      GROUP BY STATE
```

What you get from that subquery is a column of positive integers, UNLESS no states have catlovers='Y' and if that happened the subquery would return NULL.

Now consider

```
SELECT MIN(CATLOVERS)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(ID) AS CATLOVERS
      FROM A10
      WHERE CATLOVERS = 'Y'
      GROUP BY STATE)x
```

So the MIN() of a series of positive integers might be one, and this subquery would return a single row of 1, unless the first subquery returned NULL which would also cause NULL here.

Hence this next subquery will just list IDs where the count(ID) = a minimum or no rows if the earlier subqueries are NULL

```
SELECT ID
  FROM A10
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING COUNT(ID) =
   (SELECT MIN(CATLOVERS)
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(ID) AS CATLOVERS
          FROM A10
          WHERE CATLOVERS = 'Y'
          GROUP BY STATE)x)
```

**Try running your subqueries independently to study what is happening.**

see: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/577188

Comment: The answer from the previous poster was wrong anyways... Still taking a look at your tips, which I greatly appreciate.  Just needed some hints to get me on the right track

Comment: @EarthlingPerson - I would say your problem statement wasn't clear, I wouldn't blame the other answer. Be well - the other answer is gone.

Comment: Directly from the assignment: "Create a view named A10T1 that will display the State for every state that has no people in the A10 table with a Cat value of Y. The column heading should be State and the rows should be sorted by State."

Comment: Have you learned about LEFT JOIN? If you left join to a subquery of states with catlovers but then list only those rows with no matching rows (sometimes called a "left excluding join") you should get what you need.

Answer (score -1):

first you need to create view:

```
CREATE OR replace VIEW a10t1 
AS 
  SELECT state 
  FROM   a10 
  WHERE  state IS NOT NULL 
         AND id IN (SELECT id 
                    FROM   a10 
                    GROUP  BY id 
                    HAVING Count(id) = (SELECT Min(catlovers) 
                                        FROM   (SELECT Count(id) AS CATLOVERS 
                                                FROM   a10 
                                                WHERE  cat = 'Y' 
                                                GROUP  BY state))) 
  ORDER  BY state;
```

then you can select from that view like this:

```
select * from a10t1
```

Comment: what was the point of copying a query that does not work? (there is a syntax error, and the result is wrong) and full solution does not aid in learning....